# Unable to add struts 2 support to netbeans 7.4

Tags: struts2, netbeans-7, netbeans-plugins

this plugin requires plugin Editor Library to be installed.

```
The plugin Editor Library is requested in version >= 2.10.1.10.2 (release version 2) but only 3.46.1.22.43 (of release version different from 2) was found.  
The following plugin is affected:       Struts2 Support
```

Comment: *Struts2 Support* is this the name of the plugin?

Comment: @RomanC... yes the plugin i'm trying to install is "struts2 support"
the default installation of netbeans 7.4 provides support for struts1.3 but not for struts 2.x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now i have resolved another plugin for Struts 2 support. This plugin is called  [Netbeans Struts2 Plug-in](http://sourceforge.net/projects/struts2nbplugin) and its a re-pack for the plugin i was trying to install. Though this plugin in not certified but it is working good. The developers have tested it on netbeans 7.4 but i'm using it not netbeans8 and i have not suffered any issues.

I have found another way, that is using maven. That is also a good way but i would not recommend it if you have slow internet connection.